# Drag and drop a shortcut on to HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm trying to build a local HTA (HTML Application) that will send me to a website I designate. I've got most of it working, as in it currently allows me to type in an address and choose whether to open that URL in either Internet Explorer or Firefox (both in normal and in private).

What I'm asking is if there is a vbscript I can add onto my HTA that will allow me to drag and drop a shortcut that is on my desktop and click a button to do the same as typing it out.  Essentially, I would love for it to be similar to Google Image search. Like you can either type in or drag and drop an image to search. This is just for me to quickly open webpages that I have a shortcut saved. I know i could use the favorites option, but I often use many different computers and I have a flash drive that has all my stuff on it.

Comment: What i have is an HTA that allows me to type in a url and click submit and it goes to said url. I also have a vbscript that allows me to drop a .url shortcut on it, and it goes to the website that it specifies. I was looking for a way to possibly implement a box of some sort on the hta, and would run the vbscript when I dropped the .url file onto it. I'm not quite sure how to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

You want to drag file (url shortcut in this case) and drop it inside open .hta window? If so then looks like what you are looking for is not yet implemented in HTML Application.

**Edit**

If you have recent Internet Explorer version (9+) then you can play with the HTML5 native 
[drag and drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) feature. As I'm on XP where IE8 is the most upper version, I can't help 
in that challenge.

If that so difficult or not applicable then may consider plan B, where can make a function 
on start up that scan your `Desktop` for `*.URL` files and populate them in [Select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element, so you'll end with something like:

```
<select id="urlList">
  <option value="" selected>---</option>
  <option value="http://...">Shortcut1.url</option>
  <option value="http://...">Shortcut2.url</option>
</select>
<input id="urlAddress" type="text">
```

...and can control it with `OnChange` event by including a handler into your `Head` section:

```
Sub urlList_OnChange()
    Document.All.urlAddress.Value = _
        Me.Options(Me.selectedIndex).Value
End Sub
```

Here is a quick snippet to get started.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strDesktop)

For Each f In fld.Files
    If f.Type = "Internet Shortcut" Then
        MsgBox f.Path & vbNewLine & ReadURL(f.Path)
    End If
Next

Function ReadURL(urlFile)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        With .OpenTextFile(urlFile, 1)
            .SkipLine
            ReadURL = (Split(.ReadLine, "="))(1)
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I understand that it is not implemented for an hta, but I have seen some other hta files that allow that using vbscript, I'm just not that skilled at vbscript to tweak it for my needs. I have one that does allow drag and drop, but it doesn't quite work and I don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, see this article from Hey, Scripting Guy (the best resource for Vbscript and Powershell stuff). Dragging something onto a shortcut is almost the same as passing parameters to a script (HTA here).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/04/20/how-can-i-pass-command-line-variables-to-an-hta-when-it-starts.aspx

Comment: Thank you peter, I have already seen and used that article and I'm not sure how to implement what it is saying for my needs. I'm looking for a way to keep the hta open and have a box of some sort where I can drag and drop a url shortcut that is on my desktop and it pull the url from that file and go to the website.

Comment: The technique i propose is not to dop on a window with the hta but on a shortcvut to the HTA. If you want to drop on a target inside the HTA window it would likely be javascript code you need so you'd have to adapt your question.

Comment: I understand, but I was asking for vbscript solution, in particular. If I am required to use javascript instead that won't be a problem, I'll just have to change my code from vbscript to javascript.